# Why I can comment only on my own questions?

Tags: support

I can comment only under my questions, and only to respond to other comments, but the same time I can't comment under questions that wasn't asked by me. Thou it seems weird to me, cuz I can post an answer. Why is that ? Where I can find related info, I have 45 reputation, or is it about badges not reputations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 50 in rep to be able to place comments [FAQ](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)